# Prevent Files from automatically adding directories to the sidebar?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell

If I manually search through my directory hierarchy using the Files app (Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome 42.9), folders I visit get automatically added to the sidebar (below Trash and above +Other Locations). How can I disable this behavior, so that Other Locations only contains directors I place there manually?

Acceptable answers will restrict themselves to Gnome (I appreciate that there are other desktop environments, window managers, etc. feel welcome to comment about these), even if the answer is some flavor of "You can't."

**Edit: Some relevant info:**

1. I am describing unintentional additions to the sidebar (i.e. not by me dragging a folder icon over the 'Other Locations' line in the sidebar. (Is there another way new directories get added to the sidebar?).
2. I am using Nautilus (= Files).
3. I have not installed Nautilus extensions that I know of.
4. I have not modified Nautilus that I know of.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the information provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's an unreproducible bug and you can't do anything but to reinstall Nautilus or to try its Nighty version.

You may for example have installed a Nautilus extension that is not part of the packages provided by Ubuntu that mess up your Files.